# How to add additional data points around each point in 1d array with normal distribution?

Tags: python, numpy

A. How to change `[1, 5, 10]` to `[0.9,0.98,1,1.02,1.1,  4.9,4.98,5,5.02,5.1,  9.9,9.98,10,10.02,10.1]` ?

B. In more general form how to change a 1D array with a unique density distribution to a larger 1D array (with a lot more data points) but keep the original density distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.add.outer`:

```
>>> numpy.add.outer(numpy.array([1, 5, 10]), numpy.array([-0.1, -0.02, 0, 0.02, 0.1])).ravel()
array([ 0.9 ,  0.98,  1.  ,  1.02,  1.1 ,  4.9 ,  4.98,  5.  ,  5.02,
        5.1 ,  9.9 ,  9.98, 10.  , 10.02, 10.1 ])
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate any suggestions you might have for for part B of my question.